# Delete node from XML file while reading it with XmlReader?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a script that reads XML node by node using `XMLReader`:

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('xmlfile.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument;

while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item');
while ($z->name === 'item')
{
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

    //I read the node here 
    print_r($node);

    //Here I want to delete it
    //////////////////////////

    //move to next node
    $z->next('item');
}
```

**I want to delete the node from XML file after reading it** to avoid reading same data multiple times when calling the script again. What is the best way to do it? Am I able to do it while reading the file?

I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLReader has a partner called XMLWriter. So for large XML files you read the XML file using XMLReader while writing the filtered/modified data using XMLWriter into a new file.

Expanding a part of the file into DOM allows easier reading and modifications of this part but you will need to use XMLWriter to serialize the XML structure into the new file.

I implemented features (including a `collapse()` method) for that into [FluentDOM](https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM). Here is an usage example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<persons>
  <person><name>Alice</name></person>
  <person><name>Bob</name></person>
  <person><name>Charlie</name></person>
</persons>
XML;

// Create the target writer and add the root element
$writer = new \FluentDOM\XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('persons');

// load the source into a reader
$reader = new \FluentDOM\XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml));

// iterate the person elements - the iterator expands them into a DOM element node
foreach (new \FluentDOM\XMLReader\SiblingIterator($reader, 'person') as $person) {
  /** @var \FluentDOM\DOM\Element $person */
  // ignore "Bob"
  if ($person('string(name)') !== 'Bob') {
    // write expanded node to the output
    $writer->collapse($person);
  }
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persons>
 <person>
  <name>Alice</name>
 </person>
 <person>
  <name>Charlie</name>
 </person>
</persons>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the document while reading it .. at least not without a lot of messy inefficient code.

Best approach would be:

1) Read the entire document into a second `DOMDocument` object.

2) As you read nodes one by one from your `XMLReader` input stream, find the corresponding nodes in the `DOMDocument` and remove them after you are done. Be careful not to delete nodes that have children you have not yet reviewed.

3) When done save the new `DomDocument` to a new file name and use this as your input source for next edit session.

You will be an expert on `DomDocument` manipulation when you are done.

Post a new question if you run into problems.

Comment: I would prefer not to read the entire document into memory every time. I also hoped it is possible to do it without creating new files. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well its unavoidable, and ThW has made an impressive set of tools in FluentDom!